# Get Json Files via API url into Google Cloud

Tags: json, api, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-api

quite new to Google Cloud Platform and having the following task: I get a dynamic .json file via an API url. Now I want to store those .json Files in a given interval on one of the GCP Databases. 
So my question is, which DB Service should I use and how do I get the .json files from the url saved into the data base. I had a look If this could work with Cloud Functions, but haven't really found any solution.

Thanks in advance

Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For instance if you use Django/Python with Google App Engine.

- Create a Google Cloud account with Google Storage/Google App Engine activated. (These are extensive steps, if you need further help please elaborate further)
- Create an API with urls.py
- Associate the api call with the following fuction :

> class JSONFileView(APIView):
>
> ```
>    @method_decorator(login_required(login_url='/login/'))
>    def get(self, request, filename):
>        root_path = request.user.username + "-" + str(request.user.id) + '/'
>        file_path = os.path.join(root_path, filename, 'yourfile.data', 'yourfile.json')
>
>        storage_client = storage.Client(project=settings.PROJECT_ID, credentials=settings.GS_CREDENTIALS)
>        bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(settings.GS_BUCKET_NAME)
>        blob = bucket.get_blob(file_path)
>        if blob != None:
>            json_data = str(blob.download_as_string(raw_download=True).decode('utf8'))
>        else:
>            json_data = {}
>            return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
>
>    return Response(json_data)
> ```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That should work. Do you know if a request like this is also possible with Cloud Functions?

Comment: This can practically run both in Google App Engine and Google Cloud Functions. Think about this as a routing from your application to Google Storage. The user should have the privilage to access the resource whihc is handled by decorator, then signed_url is generated and finally the json is returned, which is actually stored in Google Storage.

Comment: If you also agree, please select this one as correct answer.